# A Key-Value pair containing Key-Value pair in JSON?

Tags: json, parsing

Should this be accepted as a valid JSON object?

```
{"name":"First":"Last"}
```

Assuming that {"name": something else} where something else is a key-value pair : <"First":"Last">.

I've seen some threads that discuss this and I've found that it's certainly valid to use syntax like {"name":{"First":"Last"}} but in this case it's not a key:value pair of key:value pair, this is going to be a <key-value pair of <object of < key-value pair > >>.

Should a pure <key:value pair of <key:value pair>> be accepted as a valid <strike>object</strike> key-value pair by the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not have a "key-value" type. So, no, that's not valid syntax and it doesn't correspond to any JSON value.

You could use either of the following:

- `{"name": ["Jane", "Doe"]}`
- `{"name": {"first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"}`

I don't see how you could describe `"Jane": "Doe"` as a key-value pair, but perhaps that's not what you meant. I think my second example comes close to what you're talking about, but maybe not.

Comment: I just try to determine whether certain .json is a valid one or not, writing a parser.

Comment: For example, in C# this is a valid expression: "Value = value.Parent = this;",  if JSON interpreted ":" like "=", then it probably would've been possible, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ivan: JSON doesn't have variables or assignments; it's a data description language. And the C# expression does not create any kind of key-value object, nor a tuple in any sense of the word; it's a chained assignment, the same as `a = b = 0` (which only makes sense if `a` and `b` are names whose bindings can be assigned). In short, JSON doesn't interpret `:` as `=`, and C# doesn't interpret `=` as creating a key-value pair.

Comment: Anyway, there's a complete JSON syntax [as a railroad diagram here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html); if you want to write a parser, you should focus on that.